# Is there a way to use UDP to find a server started by a TcpListener?

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin

I have this server running:

```
this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
this.tcpListener.Start();
```

I need to know how can i start a multicast/broadcast signal to find ips that are running servers without trying one by one, using async threads its fast but i want to do it the right way. What kind of socket or method is the best in this case?

Comment: You have to try one by one. A TCP listener won't listen to broadcasts.

Comment: Also, UDP and TCP are two different protocols. You can't use one to find something listening on the other.

Comment: So i will need to star another server ( udp one this time ) if i want to use broadcasting?

Comment: I'm not sure what broadcasting has to do with this. And aren't you trying to find something listening on TCP?

Comment: For example; make your servers to send some data periodically to a *multicast* address. Any application listening to that multicast address can find alive servers easily. Or visa versa, your servers can listen a *multicast* address and respond to a message send by your application.

Comment: I need my client to know the ip it needs to connect: client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(??)));
So i tough about running other server before and then sendind a broadcast signal from the client to find what device is ready to receive its connection

Comment: You need to start a UDPCLient and listen on a specific port on a specific multicastaddress. Via a ping send ( and pong response) to all listening servers you can discover them and find out their IP. Take a look at: http://www.jarloo.com/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/